# Is it absolutely the case that arrays are used by reference in other modules in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I have

```
// file cars.js
var bodyshop = require('./bodyshop')

var connections = [];

many functions which operate on connections. adding them, changing them etc.

    code in this file includes things like
    bodyshop.meld(blah)
    bodyshop.mix(blah)

exports.connections = connections
```

and then

```
// file bodyshop.js
let cars = require('./cars');

even more functions which operate on connections. adding them, changing them etc.

    code in this file includes things like
    cars.connections[3].color = pink
    cars.connections.splice(deleteMe, 1)

module.exports = { meld, mix, flatten }
```

1. Is it absolutely honestly the case that code in bodyshop such as `cars.connections.splice(deleteMe, 1)` will indeed delete an item from "the" connections (ie, the one and only connections, declared in cars.js) and code in bodyshop such as `cars.connections[3].color = pink` will indeed change the color of index 3 of "the" self-same one and only connections?
2. Is it quite OK / safe / acceptable that I used the syntax "module.exports = { }" at the end of bodyshop, rather than three lines like "exports.meld = meld" ?
3. Is this sentence indeed to totally correct?? *"In Node.js if you export from M an array, when using the array in another module X which requires M, the array will be by reference in X, i.e. not by copy"* ... ?

Comment: I believe it's a bad way of implementation if you are declaring a global array and modifying it with many methods and exporting it this way. I would prefer to create a method and exports it, let this method link other methods to modify and finally, you can return the converted array.

Comment: @kgangadhar - I really understand that valuable comment, however, in this question I am literally asking the question at hand ... you could consider the code sample *purely an example*.  cheers!

Comment: Arrays are always passed by reference in Javascript including when exporting.  So, any array method that mutates the existing array such as `.splice()` will affect everyone who is using that array.  Array methods that don't mutate the array such as `.filter()` or `.concat()` create new arrays so they don't affect the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created two files with the following methods and the array as you mentioned.

First  File: test1.js

```
const testArray = [];
const getArray = () => {
    return testArray;
};
module.exports = {
    testArray,
    getArray
}
```

Second  File: test2.js

```
const { testArray, getArray } = require('./test1');

console.log('testing the required array before modifying it');
console.log(getArray());
testArray.push('test');
console.log('testing the method result after modifying the required array content');
console.log(getArray());
```

If you can create the mentioned files and run them locally, you will see the following result.

```
>node test2.js
testing the required array before modifying it
[]
testing the method result after modifying the required array content
[ 'test' ]
```

The points observed is,

2. yes, it's okay if you want to export it with the syntax `module.exports = { }`, It not much an issue.
3. If any of the methods modify this array outside of the required file, it will affect here as well, This because `require` will be a reference, not a copy.

The one possible solution will be creating a JSON copy of it while `requiring` as below:

```
const { testArray, getArray } = require('./test1');
const testArrayCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(testArray));

console.log('testing the required array before modifying it');
console.log(getArray());
testArrayCopy.push('test');
console.log('testing the method result after modifying the required array content');
console.log(getArray());
```

This is the result:

```
>node test2.js
testing the required array before modifying it
[]
testing the method result after modifying the required array content
[]
```

Note: JSON copy will not help you in parsing DateTime properly.